# Obtener URL actual con WWW::Mechanize PERL

Tags: http, perl, mechanize

¿Me podrían ayudar a obtener la URL actual en la que estoy ubicado (después de hacer un login)?

```perl
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $urlActual;
my $url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
my $palabra;
my $username = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
my $password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$mech->get($url);
$mech->form_name('menubar_login');
$mech->field(txt_login => $username);
$mech->field(txt_clave => $password);
$mech->click();
my $app_content = $mech->content();

$urlActual = top.frame.location.href
Printf($urlActual)
```

Me salta un error en la penúltima linea.

---

**Editado:**
Y luego de recibir algunas respuestas sobre usar `$mech->uri()`, me encuentro con el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como viene en su documentación:

> `$mech->uri()`
>
> Devuelve la URI actual como un objeto URI.

[Referencia a la documentación](http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/WWW-Mechanize-1.83/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm)

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje de error indica que te falta punto y coma (`;`) en la línea 18.

Solución:  `$mech->uri();` (agregar el punto y coma)

Answer (score 1):

Las dos últimas líneas no siguen la sintaxis de Perl. Más bien parecen de JavaScript.

Debes usar el método uri().